# I am displaying some content using dangerouslySetInnerHtml in Reactjs for a blog page, but bullet points are not showing

Tags: reactjs, webview, html5-canvas, html-lists, dangerouslysetinnerhtml

I am displaying some content using dangerouslySetInnerHtml in Reactjs for a blog page, but bullet points are not showing, however the same code and page is being used in another project and that is perfectly working fine. Unable to get whats the problem here i will be attaching the code. The renders fine, the only problem here is that it does not shows bullets for

tags. May be some alternative to dangerouslySetInnerHTMl can solve the problem for me.

Here is how my Content looks like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" />

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

<style type="text/css">
<!--
@font-face {
  font-family: 'DuplicateIonic-Regular';
  src: url("") format("embedded-opentype");
  src: url("") format("opentype"), url("") format("woff"), url("") format("truetype"), url("") format("svg");
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal; 
}
@font-face {
  font-family: 'DuplicateIonic-Medium';
  src: url("") format("embedded-opentype");
  src: url("") format("opentype"), url(""), url("") format("truetype"), url("") format("svg");
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal; 
}
@font-face {
  font-family: 'DuplicateIonic-Bold';
  src: url("") format("embedded-opentype");
  src: url("") format("opentype"), url("") format("woff"), url("") format("truetype"), url("") format("svg");
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal; 
}

body {
    padding-right: 8px;
    padding-left: 8px;
}

img {
    max-width: 100%;
}

.textbody {
    font-size: 15px;
    color: #6B6767;
    line-height: 130%;
    font-family: 'Helvetica', Arial, sans-serif;
}

.textbody hr {
    margin: 20px 0 30px 0;
    border: 0;
    border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.textbody a {
    color: red;
}

.textbody h1,
.textbody h2,
.textbody h3,
.textbody h4 {
    color: #E2051B;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-family: BurlingamePro-Bold, Arial;
    margin: 0;
    line-height: 140%;
}

.textbody h1.grey,
.textbody h2.grey,
.textbody h3.grey,
.textbody h4.grey {
    color: #666;
}

.textbody h2 {
    font-size: 16px;
}

.textbody h2.dark {
    color: #555;
    font-size: 18px;
}

.textbody h2.dark-thin {
    color: #333;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: BurlingamePro-Bold, Arial;
    font-size: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    line-height: 130%;
}

.textbody h2.pink {
    color: #F16A7C;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: BurlingamePro-Bold, Arial;
    font-size: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    line-height: 130%;
}

.textbody p {
    margin-bottom: 25px;
}

.textbody table {
    width: 100%;
    border-collapse:collapse;
}

.textbody table,
.textbody th,
.textbody td {
    border: 1px solid #6B6767;
    padding: 3%;
    line-height: 120%;
    font-size: 15px;
}

.textbody a {
    color: #E2051B;
}

.textbody a.btn {
    color: #fff;
}

.textbody .special-info {
    border-top: 2px solid #ededed;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #ededed;
    padding: 20px 0;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.textbody .special-info h2 {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.textbody .caption {
    color: #666;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    font-style: italic;
}

.textbody .embed-video {
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 56.25%;
    /* 16:9 */
    padding-top: 25px;
    height: 0;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
}

.textbody .embed-video iframe {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.textbody ul,
.textbody ol {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 0 0 25px;
    text-align: left;
}

.textbody ul li,
.textbody ol li {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.textbody ol {
    padding-left: 40px;
}

.textbody ol.no-indent {
    padding-left: 25px;
}

.textbody .qns {
    color: #E2051B;
    font-family: BurlingamePro-Bold, Arial;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.textbody .ans {
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.textbody .no-margin li {
    margin: 0;
}

.textbody ol.alpha {
    list-style-type: lower-alpha;
}

.textbody .table-wrap {
    width: 100%;
    overflow-x: auto;
}

.textbody .bluebar {
    background-color: #0070b9;
}

.textbody .pinkbar {
    background-color: #ef4270;
}

.textbody section.border-bottom {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ededed;
    padding-bottom: 25px;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
}

.textbody section.border-bottom.no-border {
    border: 0;
    padding-bottom: 0;
}

.textbody .height300 {
    height: 300px;
}

.textbody .height200 {
    height: 200px;
}

/* 12 Points Style */
.font30{font-size:30px;}
.offers-bg{background-image:url('https://www.frasersexperience.com/files/images/frx1212-bg2.jpg');}
.date-container{text-align:center;margin-bottom:35px;}
.date{
    display:inline-block;background-color:#F5C046;border:3px solid #000;padding:15px; 
    font-family:DuplicateIonic-Bold;color:#000;}
.deal-2column{margin-bottom:20px;}
.deal-img-wrap{display:inline-block;position:relative}
.tag{position:absolute;top:0;left:0;display:inline-block;width:42%;text-align:left}
.deal-2column{
    margin-left:0;
    margin-right:0;
}
/* End 12 Points Style */

*{
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.text-right {
    text-align: right!important;
}

.text-center {
    text-align: center!important;
}

.row{
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    margin-right: -15px;
    margin-left: -15px;
}

.no-gutters {
  margin-right: 0;
  margin-left: 0;
}

.no-gutters > .col,
.no-gutters > [class*="col-"] {
  padding-right: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
}

.col-1, .col-2, .col-3, .col-4, .col-5, .col-6, .col-7, .col-8, .col-9, .col-10, .col-11, .col-12, .col,
.col-auto, .col-sm-1, .col-sm-2, .col-sm-3, .col-sm-4, .col-sm-5, .col-sm-6, .col-sm-7, .col-sm-8, .col-sm-9, .col-sm-10, .col-sm-11, .col-sm-12, .col-sm,
.col-sm-auto, .col-md-1, .col-md-2, .col-md-3, .col-md-4, .col-md-5, .col-md-6, .col-md-7, .col-md-8, .col-md-9, .col-md-10, .col-md-11, .col-md-12, .col-md,
.col-md-auto, .col-lg-1, .col-lg-2, .col-lg-3, .col-lg-4, .col-lg-5, .col-lg-6, .col-lg-7, .col-lg-8, .col-lg-9, .col-lg-10, .col-lg-11, .col-lg-12, .col-lg,
.col-lg-auto, .col-xl-1, .col-xl-2, .col-xl-3, .col-xl-4, .col-xl-5, .col-xl-6, .col-xl-7, .col-xl-8, .col-xl-9, .col-xl-10, .col-xl-11, .col-xl-12, .col-xl,
.col-xl-auto {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 1px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
}

.col {
  -ms-flex-preferred-size: 0;
  flex-basis: 0;
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  -ms-flex-positive: 1;
  flex-grow: 1;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.col-auto {
  -webkit-box-flex: 0;
  -ms-flex: 0 0 auto;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  width: auto;
  max-width: none;
}

.col-1 {
  -webkit-box-flex: 0;
  -ms-flex: 0 0 8.333333%;
  flex: 0 0 8.333333%;
  max-width: 8.333333%;
}

.col-2 {
  -webkit-box-flex: 0;
  -ms-flex: 0 0 16.666667%;
  flex: 0 0 16.666667%;
  max-width: 16.666667%;
}

.col-3 {
  -webkit-box-flex: 0;
  -ms-flex: 0 0 25%;
  flex: 0 0 25%;
  max-width: 25%;
}

.col-4 {
  -webkit-box-flex: 0;
  -ms-flex: 0 0 33.333333%;
  flex: 0 0 33.333333%;
  max-width: 33.333333%;
}

.col-5 {
  -webkit-box-flex: 0;
  -ms-flex: 0 0 41.666667%;
  flex: 0 0 41.666667%;
  max-width: 41.666667%;
}

.col-6 {
  -webkit-box-flex: 0;
  -ms-flex: 0 0 50%;
  flex: 0 0 50%;
  max-width: 50%;
}

.col-7 {
  -webkit-box-flex: 0;
  -ms-flex: 0 0 58.333333%;
  flex: 0 0 58.333333%;
  max-width: 58.333333%;
}

.col-8 {
  -webkit-box-flex: 0;
  -ms-flex: 0 0 66.666667%;
  flex: 0 0 66.666667%;
  max-width: 66.666667%;
}

.col-9 {
  -webkit-box-flex: 0;
  -ms-flex: 0 0 75%;
  flex: 0 0 75%;
  max-width: 75%;
}

.col-10 {
  -webkit-box-flex: 0;
  -ms-flex: 0 0 83.333333%;
  flex: 0 0 83.333333%;
  max-width: 83.333333%;
}

.col-11 {
  -webkit-box-flex: 0;
  -ms-flex: 0 0 91.666667%;
  flex: 0 0 91.666667%;
  max-width: 91.666667%;
}

.col-12 {
  -webkit-box-flex: 0;
  -ms-flex: 0 0 100%;
  flex: 0 0 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.order-first {
  -webkit-box-ordinal-group: 0;
  -ms-flex-order: -1;
  order: -1;
}

.order-last {
  -webkit-box-ordinal-group: 14;
  -ms-flex-order: 13;
  order: 13;
}

.order-0 {
  -webkit-box-ordinal-group: 1;
  -ms-flex-order: 0;
  order: 0;
}

.order-1 {
  -webkit-box-ordinal-group: 2;
  -ms-flex-order: 1;
  order: 1;
}

.order-2 {
  -webkit-box-ordinal-group: 3;
  -ms-flex-order: 2;
  order: 2;
}

.order-3 {
  -webkit-box-ordinal-group: 4;
  -ms-flex-order: 3;
  order: 3;
}

.order-4 {
  -webkit-box-ordinal-group: 5;
  -ms-flex-order: 4;
  order: 4;
}

.order-5 {
  -webkit-box-ordinal-group: 6;
  -ms-flex-order: 5;
  order: 5;
}

.order-6 {
  -webkit-box-ordinal-group: 7;
  -ms-flex-order: 6;
  order: 6;
}

.order-7 {
  -webkit-box-ordinal-group: 8;
  -ms-flex-order: 7;
  order: 7;
}

.order-8 {
  -webkit-box-ordinal-group: 9;
  -ms-flex-order: 8;
  order: 8;
}

.order-9 {
  -webkit-box-ordinal-group: 10;
  -ms-flex-order: 9;
  order: 9;
}

.order-10 {
  -webkit-box-ordinal-group: 11;
  -ms-flex-order: 10;
  order: 10;
}

.order-11 {
  -webkit-box-ordinal-group: 12;
  -ms-flex-order: 11;
  order: 11;
}

.order-12 {
  -webkit-box-ordinal-group: 13;
  -ms-flex-order: 12;
  order: 12;
}

.offset-1 {
  margin-left: 8.333333%;
}

.offset-2 {
  margin-left: 16.666667%;
}

.offset-3 {
  margin-left: 25%;
}

.offset-4 {
  margin-left: 33.333333%;
}

.offset-5 {
  margin-left: 41.666667%;
}

.offset-6 {
  margin-left: 50%;
}

.offset-7 {
  margin-left: 58.333333%;
}

.offset-8 {
  margin-left: 66.666667%;
}

.offset-9 {
  margin-left: 75%;
}

.offset-10 {
  margin-left: 83.333333%;
}

.offset-11 {
  margin-left: 91.666667%;
}

.flex-row {
  -webkit-box-orient: horizontal !important;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal !important;
  -ms-flex-direction: row !important;
  flex-direction: row !important;
}

.flex-column {
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical !important;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal !important;
  -ms-flex-direction: column !important;
  flex-direction: column !important;
}

.flex-row-reverse {
  -webkit-box-orient: horizontal !important;
  -webkit-box-direction: reverse !important;
  -ms-flex-direction: row-reverse !important;
  flex-direction: row-reverse !important;
}

.flex-column-reverse {
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical !important;
  -webkit-box-direction: reverse !important;
  -ms-flex-direction: column-reverse !important;
  flex-direction: column-reverse !important;
}

.flex-wrap {
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap !important;
  flex-wrap: wrap !important;
}

.flex-nowrap {
  -ms-flex-wrap: nowrap !important;
  flex-wrap: nowrap !important;
}

.flex-wrap-reverse {
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap-reverse !important;
  flex-wrap: wrap-reverse !important;
}

.justify-content-start {
  -webkit-box-pack: start !important;
  -ms-flex-pack: start !important;
  justify-content: flex-start !important;
}

.justify-content-end {
  -webkit-box-pack: end !important;
  -ms-flex-pack: end !important;
  justify-content: flex-end !important;
}

.justify-content-center {
  -webkit-box-pack: center !important;
  -ms-flex-pack: center !important;
  justify-content: center !important;
}

.justify-content-between {
  -webkit-box-pack: justify !important;
  -ms-flex-pack: justify !important;
  justify-content: space-between !important;
}

.justify-content-around {
  -ms-flex-pack: distribute !important;
  justify-content: space-around !important;
}

.align-items-start {
  -webkit-box-align: start !important;
  -ms-flex-align: start !important;
  align-items: flex-start !important;
}

.align-items-end {
  -webkit-box-align: end !important;
  -ms-flex-align: end !important;
  align-items: flex-end !important;
}

.align-items-center {
  -webkit-box-align: center !important;
  -ms-flex-align: center !important;
  align-items: center !important;
}

.align-items-baseline {
  -webkit-box-align: baseline !important;
  -ms-flex-align: baseline !important;
  align-items: baseline !important;
}

.align-items-stretch {
  -webkit-box-align: stretch !important;
  -ms-flex-align: stretch !important;
  align-items: stretch !important;
}

.align-content-start {
  -ms-flex-line-pack: start !important;
  align-content: flex-start !important;
}

.align-content-end {
  -ms-flex-line-pack: end !important;
  align-content: flex-end !important;
}

.align-content-center {
  -ms-flex-line-pack: center !important;
  align-content: center !important;
}

.align-content-between {
  -ms-flex-line-pack: justify !important;
  align-content: space-between !important;
}

.align-content-around {
  -ms-flex-line-pack: distribute !important;
  align-content: space-around !important;
}

.align-content-stretch {
  -ms-flex-line-pack: stretch !important;
  align-content: stretch !important;
}

.align-self-auto {
  -ms-flex-item-align: auto !important;
  align-self: auto !important;
}

.align-self-start {
  -ms-flex-item-align: start !important;
  align-self: flex-start !important;
}

.align-self-end {
  -ms-flex-item-align: end !important;
  align-self: flex-end !important;
}

.align-self-center {
  -ms-flex-item-align: center !important;
  align-self: center !important;
}

.align-self-baseline {
  -ms-flex-item-align: baseline !important;
  align-self: baseline !important;
}

.align-self-stretch {
  -ms-flex-item-align: stretch !important;
  align-self: stretch !important;
}

.mm-list {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.mm-list .item {
  width: 49%;
  margin-top: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 2px;
  text-align: center;
  height: 250px;
  position: relative;
}
.mm-list .item .tag {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #E2051B;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  font-family: BurlingamePro-Bold, serif;
  font-size: 14px;
}
.mm-list .item .thumb {
  position: relative;
}
.mm-list .item .thumb img {
  height: 150px;
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
.mm-list .item .thumb .promo {
  background-color: #FFCC00;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  font-family: BurlingamePro-Bold, serif;
  padding: 5px 0;
  color: #000;
}
.mm-list .item .thumb .promo .text {
  font-size: 12px;
}
.mm-list .item .thumb .promo .code {
  font-size: 15px;
}
.mm-list .item .storename {
  color: #E2051B;
  font-family: BurlingamePro-Bold, serif;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
.mm-list .item .mall {
  color: #666;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-family: BurlingamePro-Bold, Arial;
  line-height: 130%;
  display: table;
  height: 55px;
  width: 100%;
}
.mm-list .item .mall .text {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
}
.mm-list .item {
    width: 32%;
}
.noapp{
    display:none
}
-->
</style>

<script>
function sendToApp(obj){
    var data = JSON.stringify(obj);
    postMessage(data);
}
</script>

</head>

<body bgcolor='#eaeaea'><div class="textbody"><p>
    Love to shop? It&rsquo;s time you got rewarded for it!<br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    </p>
<p>
    <img alt="" src="" style="; ;" /></p>
<p>
    !</p>
<div>
    <span style="color:#f00;"><strong>TERMS AND CONDITIONS</strong></span></div>
<div>
    &nbsp;</div>
<ul>
    <li>
        </li>
    <li>
        </li>
    <li>
        </li>
    <li>
        </li>
    <li>
        </li>
    <li>
        </li>
    <li>
    </li>
    <li>
        </li>
    <li>
        </li>
    <li>
        </li>
    <li>
        </li>
    <li>
        </li>
    <li>
        </li>
    <li>
        </li>
</ul>
</div></body>

</html>
```

Here is how i am trying to display this:

```
 <div style={{ paddingLeft: scale(11), paddingRight: scale(11) }}>
                    <div
                        dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
                            __html: this.state.content
                        }}></div>
                </div>
```